# Alternatives to not having Adobe AIR native extension for desktop Java

Tags: java, air, flex4

**Background**

We have an AIR client application backed by a Java backend.

In our application, we have a complex data grid that captures a lot of data at once. Each individual data cell may potentially trigger heavy calculations/processing. This will happen repeatedly until the user is satisfied and saves a final version.

The nature of some of the processing requires a large part of it to be done by Java. Add in a lot of users, and we have a definite server performance issue.

We need to move the bulk of the processing to the client side instead.

**Problem**

Now, when a user submits the final set of inputs, the server will perform one final run of the calculations before persisting them. Which means we need a set of Java classes that can perform all the calculations/processing that are needed.

Since we're already writing the Java classes, it'd be ideal to just reuse them as a library on the client-side, rather than re-doing them in Flex and having to maintain both.

We thought Adobe AIR's native extension would be perfect - until we found out that only DLLs are supported on Windows. We can't make use of NativeProcess either due to our delivery mechanism (there's no .exe for the Java library).

**Question**

So far, we've tried Merapi, but considering it's been inactive for a while now, we're concerned about future compatibility. We're wondering if there's any other alternatives to Merapi?

Or better yet, any other potential approaches to this problem of trying creating a communication bridge between an AIR application and a Java library.

Comment: Why can't you do the client app in Java as well?

Comment: That's because our product is sitting on an internal framework that uses Flex as a front-end. So we had to stick with a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options, depending on how much work you are willing to do.

**IF you are willing to consider something other than FLEX...**

You could either go for an Applet, because:

It runs in the browser, can communicate back to your application and uses the browser resources on the client to perform the calculations.

Or, and this is my favourite, you could write a Java Webstart-deployed desktop application. That will run entirely on the client, it's NOT a resource drain on your server, can talk to the server via RMI or simple messaging, is as close to a native desktop application as you can get and updates itself, so no deployment problems.

The third option is trickier, but, in theory, you could use something like GWT to write the application in Java, and then have it converted to a Javascript app by GWT. That runs in the browser, but it has severe limitations, in my humble opinion, GWT Javascript is near unreadable and difficult to customise.

**The alternative:**

Write the app as a standard web-app and use Javascript to perform the calculations client-side. The problem is you won't be able to re-use your Java classes.

**Conclusion** (Should read, humblest opinion)

All in all, a Java Desktop Application, deployed via Webstart, looks like the best solution. It will allow you to re-use your calculations code, and it will make great use of the client-side resources as well.

Comment: One main reason we had to stick with Flex is because we have to reuse all of the Flex interface code (we have a dynamic UI engine). If we ditch Flex, it means we'd have to recreate the UI engine. We're aware that we can do this using other technologies, but unfortunately these are the constraints.

Comment: I guess you are stuck using AIR then, I don't see a way around it. You might want to start working on an alternative solution though.

Comment: Yea, we've done something workable using Merapi, but that project seems inactive now. So we're exploring other options, including using NativeProcess as a workaround.

Comment: Best of luck there, please add the answer when you find it, it will help someone in the future.